# Please help me evaluate this product involving logarithms.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, limits

Please help me evaluate this product:
$$\prod _{n=0}^{\infty } -\frac{\log \left(-\frac{1}{6 n+2}\right) \log \left(-\frac{2}{6 n+3}\right) \log \left(-\frac{1}{6 n+4}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{6 n+5}\right) \log \left(\frac{2}{6 n+6}\right)}{\log (6 n+2) \log (6 n+3) \log (6 n+4) \log (6 n+5) \log (6 n+6)}$$

I get error messages in Mathematica with the code at the bottom of the question.

I know that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } (-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{1}{6 n+2}\right) \log \left(-\frac{2}{6 n+3}\right) \log \left(-\frac{1}{6 n+4}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{6 n+5}\right) \log \left(\frac{2}{6 n+6}\right)}{\log (6 n+2) \log (6 n+3) \log (6 n+4) \log (6 n+5) \log (6 n+6)})=1$$

So the product should converge to something.

I am more interested in the numerical value than the analytic form.

The Mathematica code that gives error messages about underflow in the numerics is:

```
Clear[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, n, k]
Sum[1/(6*n + 1) - 1/(6*n + 2) - 2/(6*n + 3) - 1/(6*n + 4) + 
  1/(6*n + 5) + 2/(6*n + 6), {n, 0, Infinity}]
Print["x1"]
x1 = (x1 /. Solve[1/(6*n + 1) == 1/(6*n + 1)^x1, x1])[[1]]
Print["x2"]
x2 = (x2 /. Solve[-1/(6*n + 2) == 1/(6*n + 2)^x2, x2])[[1]]
Print["x3"]
x3 = (x3 /. Solve[-2/(6*n + 3) == 1/(6*n + 3)^x3, x3])[[1]]
Print["x4"]
x4 = (x4 /. Solve[-1/(6*n + 4) == 1/(6*n + 4)^x4, x4])[[1]]
Print["x5"]
x5 = (x5 /. Solve[1/(6*n + 5) == 1/(6*n + 5)^x5, x5])[[1]]
Print["x6"]
x6 = (x6 /. Solve[2/(6*n + 6) == 1/(6*n + 6)^x6, x6])[[1]]
Print["setting x1 equal to one which it essentially is"]
x1 = 1;
NProduct[x1*x2*x3*x4*x5*x6, {n, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
Limit[x1*x2*x3*x4*x5*x6, n -> Infinity]
```

The product I want to evaluate is:

```
NProduct[x1*x2*x3*x4*x5*x6, {n, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

Comment: $\log(-\frac{1}{6n+2})$ is undefined when $n\in \mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran How do you mean? Mathematica evaluates $\log(-\frac{1}{6n+2})$ to $\{-\log (2)+i \pi ,-\log (8)+i \pi ,-\log (14)+i \pi ,-\log (20)+i \pi \}$ for $n=1,2,3,4$

Comment: Ha Ok you refer in the complex plane, excuse me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that one of $-\frac 1{6n+2}$ and $6n+2$ is negative, so you are taking the log of a negative number.